# Objective C: How to check object type without a lot of if statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, refactoring

I am trying to set my `text` string to a URL. The following code works, but I feel like I can refactor it to make it look neater.

```
NSString *text = @“”;

id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

   id data = json[@“data”];

    if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
       id value = data[@"value"];

       if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            id url = [value valueForKey:@"url"];

          if ([url isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
             text  = url;
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

So far it has the whole "mountain of doom" going on and I want to know how can I check if the object type is correct without using so many if statements. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: This is the lite version of my code, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, there are 2 ways to make it look neater and ignore if-else-nesting-hell.

- Using `return`.

  ```
  NSString *text = @“”;

  id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

  if (![json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    return;
  }
  id data = json[@“data”];

  if (![data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    return;
  }
  id value = data[@"value"];

  if (![value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    return;
  }
  id url = [value valueForKey:@"url"];

  if (![url isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    return;
  }
  text  = url;
  ```
- Create a generic method which checks kind of class and return a safe value

  ```
  - (id)safeValueFromObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString *)key class:(Class)valueClass {
    if (![object respondsToSelector:@selector(valueForKey:)]) {
      return [[valueClass alloc] init];
    }

    id result = [object valueForKey:key];
    return [result isKindOfClass:valueClass] ? result : [[valueClass alloc] init];
  }
  ```

  Use

  ```
  NSString *text = @"";

  id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
  id data = [self safeValueFromObject:json forKey:@"data" class:NSDictionary.class];
  id value = [self safeValueFromObject:data forKey:@"value" class:NSArray.class];
  id url = [self safeValueFromObject:value forKey:@"url" class:NSString.class];
  text  = url;
  ```

Comment: I too liked the second method first one is not good with so many if statements